# machine to load into and take out from a DVD burner, burning many different ISO-images

Tags: dvd, dvd-burning

Sometimes I want to burn between 50 and 100 different DVD-Rs (single-sided ones, 4.7 Gig capacity, DVD-R). The sorce is from ISO-images on my hard-disc, and for each DVD there is a different image.

Doing this manually is a huge pain in the ass as you can imagine.

I want to buy a machine which somehow inserts blank DVDs into a burner, burns one image, takes the burned DVD out & puts it on a pile, burns next image. Discarding bad burns. Without me interventing.

My question is, what are such machines called so that I can search for prices and reviews on the net, and maybe do you have personal recommendations which one might be good?

So far I found only machines where you basically have a tower with several DVD-burners in it, which is something different. Then I found machines which are basically what I'm looking for, but the ones I found were professional grade ones for several thousand dollars (way to expensive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called duplicators, although they typically take a master disc and copy that rather than having an ISO for input.  You would want a DVD duplicator in this case.  They run a couple hundred dollars it looks like.  One that does everything including swapping discs is called an autoduplicator, and those run over $1000 because they involve robotics.

Here's a site dedicated to disc duplicators:
http://www.produplicator.com/

If you don't do it very often you may wish to simply use a DVD publishing service:
http://kunaki.com/
https://www.createspace.com/
http://www.lulu.com/publish/cd_dvd/